# What are the matrices that commute with the conjugate matrices of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm sharing this exercise from the École Polytechnique oral exam with you.

Let $\mathrm{A}\in\mathfrak{M}_{n}(\mathbf{C})$. We assume that $\mathrm{A}$ is not proportional to the identity matrix $\mathrm{I}_n$.

Let $\mathrm{M}\in\mathfrak{M}_{n}(\mathbf{C})$. We assume that $\mathrm{M}$ commutes with all matrices similar to $\mathrm{A}$. Prove that $\mathrm{M}$ is scalar.

Is the result true in $\mathfrak{M}_{n}(\mathbf{R})$?

When $n=2$, we can easily reduce it to a matrix of the form $\mathrm{diag}(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distincts ou
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha&1\\
0&\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and solve the problem. In the general case, we know that the equivalence class of $\mathrm{A}$ contains an upper triangular matrix and at least one eigenvalue in $\mathbb{C}$, but I do not see how to exploit this.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.